# How to cache response based on some flag in service worker

Tags: service-worker

I am new in progressive web application and don't know how to cache responses based on the content-type e.g. application/ javascript , image/jpg like this.
I don't want to cache request based on url's i want to cache them using some flag which is available in response headers
How can i check this. Please guide with some code snippet.
Help me out guys...thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this, we will fetch the request and then get content type from headers and also get flags from response headers and based on these value we can decide whether we need to cache that request or not